# Octave refuses to deal with the strings i pass to csvread()

Tags: octave

So I am working on an Octave script (I am relatively inexperienced with the language), and I am trying to open two csv files who's names I pass to my script as command line arguments.  Here is my script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env octave

    function plotregs(fig, regs)
      figure(fig);
      title('Foo');
      xlabel('Value');
      ylabel('Cycle #');
      grid on;

      plot(rows(regs(:, 1)), regs(:, 1),
           rows(regs(:, 2)), regs(:, 2),
           rows(regs(:, 3)), regs(:, 3),
           rows(regs(:, 4)), regs(:, 4),
           rows(regs(:, 5)), regs(:, 5),
           rows(regs(:, 6)), regs(:, 6),
           rows(regs(:, 7)), regs(:, 7),
           rows(regs(:, 8)), regs(:, 8));

      legend('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'L');
    endfunction  

    args = argv ();
    filename = strcat(cellstr(args(1)));
    typeinfo filename
    regs = csvread(filename);

    graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");

    plotregs(1, regs);

    filename = strcat(cellstr(args(2)));
    regs = csvread(filename);

    plotregs(2, regs);

    pause
```

And here is the output I get when I run the script:

```
    ans = sq_string
    error: dlmread: FILE argument must be a string or file id
    error: called from:
    error:   /usr/share/octave/3.4.3/m/io/csvread.m at line 34, column 5
    error:   /home/tnecniv/Code/Octave/regigraph/regigraph.m at line 25, column 6
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you create an executable Octave script which expects arguments yet do not provide any arguments.

First of all I would start the file as

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
```

Then one could run the script as

```
$ ./myscript.sh datafile1.csv datafile2.csv
```

But in my opinion argv() behaves a bit strange, because when no arguments are given to -say myscript.sh-, it returns the filename of the executing script, but when one or more arguments are given it contains the arguments only.

You can refer to Section 2.6 of the documentation for "Executable Octave Programs".